# immediates for MIPS I-type instructions

Tags: binary, mips

In MIPS, an I type instruction has the following format.

1. bits [31, 26] are for opcode
2. bits [25, 21] are for source register
3. bits [20, 16] are for transfer register
4. bits [15, 0] are for immediates

If the number of registers used is halved, then I will have two extra bits to use for the immediates. And if I'm assuming 2's complement form, then, I have 18 bits. So is my minimum value for the immediate \$-131072\$ and max value \$131071\$?

Comment: How are you removing 2 registers from the cpu? I'm guessing that would take a newly rebuilt cpu, which then could be built to accept 18-bit immediates in an I-type instruction?

Comment: Also, you'd want to rearrange the bits in your theoretical cpu, because coding an immediate using bits 21 & 60-1 would be rather sloppy.

Comment: I'm actually removing half the registers. And this is just theoretically speaking. Not for actual implementation.

Comment: Yes, I noticed my error on the -2 instead of 1/2 about 20 seconds after the 5 minute edit-timer for my comment expired (not to mention typing '60' instead of '16' in the second comment). :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all necessary uC architecture adjustments have been made, then you would have an *unsigned* range of 0-262144, or a *signed* range of (-)131072-131071.
Your math is correct.